# Running single cucumber test multiple times with different before steps

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-junit

I have three different feature files which hold different test scenarios: configA.feature, configB.feature, common.feature.
In the steps file I have two tagged before hooks, one for each config (A/B):

```
  @Before("@ConfigA")
  public void configA() {
    //some settings
  }

  @Before("@ConfigB")
  public void configB() {
    //some settings
  }
```

These two configs are mutually exclusive, so only one should be executed for any particular scenario execution as the second would overwrite setting done by the first.

What I want to achieve is to be able to run scenarios as follows:

- configA.feature with the ConfigA hook executed
- configB.feature with the ConfigB hook executed
- common.feature with the ConfigA hook executed
- common.feature with the ConfigB hook executed

I've tried annotating the features in the feature files as:

```
configA with @ConfigA
configB with @ConfigB
common with both @ConfigA @ConfigB
```

but this results in common.feature being always executed with both of the before hooks at the same time.

As I'm using a JUnit wrapper with Cucumber runner I've also tried creating separate test classes with @CucumberOptions.tags specified, but this didn't work for me either.

Is, what I'm trying to do, even possible with cucumber? If so then how can I achieve this?

Comment: If you gave examples of what configA and B do, why they are important and why they are different then I might be able to offer simple alternatives to what you are doing. You are probably misusing @Before tags and that is making things more difficult, but without an understanding of what you are doing I can't be sure.

Comment: effectively configA and configB set different values of a configuration flag which is responsible for different handling on some cases in the app. The app is processing some date-related data. It's supposed to act differently when the date is a holiday or a working day. And the configs change how the holidays are handled

Comment: So you should be writing steps to deal with this, not using @Before tags. Things like `Given its the holidays`, `When I ...`. @Before tags should not be used for anything application specific, they are really designed for environment settings, and to be used rarely or not at all.

Comment: In that case what I would end up with would be two copies of the scenario with just this one step being different. I was hoping it's possible to avoid this

Comment: But thats fine. The whole point of a scenario is to test a particular circumstance. You have two different circumstances If you can express that clearly and simply, its much more beneficial to have two simple scenarios that are run once, than a complex scenario that is run twice.

Comment: I take your point. One thing bugs me though - if I was able to do what I initially wanted to, then other devs were safe to assume that once they provide a scenario in the common.feature file if would be tested against both the configs. Without that solution in place someone may potentially provide just one of the scenarios. Do you have any suggestions on how this could be enforced other then just a general policy, code review etc.?

Comment: describe the configs in detail both why they are needed and how they are different and maybe I can help. Generally how you organise features, folder structure/naming and file naming guides devs. I'm not sure what you mean by a common feature file. Each feature should be about a specific piece of behaviour, there is no common feature file.

Comment: In the production environment these configs would be just an entry in some db table. When the enpoint that does processing of this particular data is truggered the that db entry would be fetched and the app would react accoringly. They are needed as the on different installations of the app it may be expected of it to act in one or the other way, and the db entry defines which is the active setting for a particular installation.

Comment: By "Common feature file" I was referring to one of the three feature files I mentioned in the initiall description. I have three feature files. Two of them have the same scenarios (Given and When parts), but have different data in the Then, and each of these files should represent one of the configs (A or B) being active. The third file, which I called the "common" one contains additional scenarios that should work exactly the same regardless of which config in the active one. I hope this description is clear enough.

Comment: so pull @configA into a step, pull @configB into a step. Use the each step in its appropriate feature file. For the common file ( the  one you want to run twice ) break it into two feature files (forget about the duplication), one with the `@configA` step and one with the `@configB` step. Now you have a simpler problem, how to deal with the duplication. I can solve that for you but only if you can show me the feature files. I have to know the context if I am to understand the duplication.